# entity_autocomplete, multiple users

Tags: 8, forms

I would like a form element able to select multiple users.

```
$form['forward_users'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#title' => t('Forward to these users (if multiple, select and add a comma \',\')'),
  '#target_type' => 'user',
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
);
```

`$form_state->getValue('forward_users')` returns only the last user ID.

I also tried this code.

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('roles', 'int_tactf')
  ->execute();

foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $temp_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($id);
  $tactf_users[$id] = $temp_user->getAccountName();
}


$form['forward_users'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Forward to these users'),
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#options' => $tactf_users,
  '#size' => 3,
);
```

In the form submission handler, `$form_state->getValue('forward_users')` doesn't return the selected users.

Comment: Please take a look at the https://www.drupal.org/project/examples project. You can find a practical answer in there. Plain text search on "entity_autocomplete".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select multiple users with a *entity_autocomplete* form field you need to use `'#tags' => TRUE` instead of `'#multiple' => TRUE`. The code you are using should be similar to the following one.

```
$form['forward_users'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#title' => t('Forward to these users (if multiple, select and add a comma \',\')'),
  '#target_type' => 'user',
  'tags' => TRUE,
);
```